# ios - show core data results in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, uilabel

I know how to set a `UILabel` and populate it with a `NSString`, so am I wrong to assume that I can load a attribute of a Core Data database into an `NSString` and show that result into an `UILabel`?

If I am right that this is possible, how do I go about that? I have bits a pieces of code I trying to piece together as I am learning how to do this:-)

I want to show this result in a normal `UIView` rather than a `UITableView`.

Cheers Jeff

Comment: What is the type on the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `NSManagedObject` classes to access your Core Data entities. For example, if you have an entity named `Person`, there should be a corresponding `Person` class (declared in `Person.h` and `Person.m`). For each attribute of that Person class, you should have a corresponding `@property`. After you've queried your data (usually using an `NSFetchRequest`), you can then access these properties and assign them to whatever UI control you wish to.

For example:

```
myLabel1.text = person.firstName;
myLabel2.text = person.lastName;
```

(assuming `firstName` and `lastName` are `NSString`s).